# Error sending a post with query params in the angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I need to make this post request, where I send the email via param, but I'm not getting it. I saw similar questions and tried to implement, but I still haven't been successful

my api : http://localhost:8080/auth/reset-password?email=myemail@email.com

```
sendEmail() {
        const email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
    
        this.loginService.sendEmail(email)
        .subscribe(() => {
            alert('ok');
        },
        erro => {
            alert('error');
            this.loginForm.reset();
        })
        
    }
```

service:

```
sendEmail(email: string) {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('email', email);
        console.log(params)
        
        return this.http.post(API_URL + 'reset-password?',{params: params});
    }
```

Comment: your API need a get, not a post: `return this.http.get(API_URL+'reset-password?email='+email)` -If really you use a post, use post with the same url-

Comment: this.http.post(API_URL + 'reset-password?',{}, {params: params}); is the correct format..